# Mouseover fade effect button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote a mouseover fade effect button with jQuery. My problem is that when the cursor mouse is over the image, it fades to white instead to `"img.b"` .Any suggestion why is it doing this?

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("img.a").hover
  ( function() { $(this).stop().animate({"opacity":"0"}, "slow");
   },
  function() {
  $(this).stop().animate({"opacity":"1"}, "slow");
  });

  });
```

Here is the CSS:

```
div.fadehover {
    position: relative;
    }

img.a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
        }

img.b {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    }
```

And here is the body code:

```
    <div class="fadehover">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="cbavota-bw.jpg" alt="" class="a" />
    <img src="cbavota.jpg" alt="" class="b" />
    </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: works here: http://jsfiddle.net/GSKer/, are your urls correct for the images? can you provide a demo for us to see your problem in action

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly working. Just make sure the path for the images are correct or not.It is working on FF,chrome and in IE.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code.
I would recommend to do this with CSS, not so resource intensive as JavaScript.

just by adding this to you code and removing the JavaScript code

```
.fadehover img {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

.fadehover img.a {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fadehover img.a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fadehover img.b {
  opacity: 1;
}

.fadehover img.b:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/surudoiryu/o032vzkn/)